# Cucumber parsing strings

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm learning how to use cucumber in java and selenium webdriver. I have the architecture in place and I'm down to one very specific problem.

```
 @When("^I login with the parameters \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\" and \"  ([^\"]*)\"")

    public void I_login_with_the_parameters(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) throws Throwable{ 

        if (arg1.equals("PRO")) {
            arg1 = "PRO";
        }
        if (arg2.equals("testleader")) {
            arg2 = "testleader";
        }
        if (arg3.equals("Chrome")) {
            arg3 = "Chrome";
        }
        assertTrue (codebase.Beoordeling_Login.correctinloggen(arg1, arg2, arg3));

    }
```

I don't understand why this code works, and when I leave out the if statements I get a null pointer exception, like this:

```
 @When("^I login with the parameters \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"")

public void I_login_with_the_parameters(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) throws Throwable{ 

    assertTrue (codebase.Beoordeling_Login.correctinloggen(arg1, arg2, arg3));

}
```

gets me:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at codebase.LoginPortal.inloggen(LoginPortal.java:14)
 at codebase.Beoordeling_Login.correctinloggen(Beoordeling_Login.java:12)
 at steps.InloggenSteps.I_login_with_the_parameters(InloggenSteps.java:32)
 at ✽.When I login with the parameters "PRO" and "testleader" and "Chrome"    (featurefiles/inloggen.feature:9)
```

When I put back the if statements it runs like I would expect, so I know that arg1, arg2 and arg3 strings are actually strings and can be used.

Why won't it let me use them in my login method and I have to re-set the strings in an ugly fashion?

edit 1:

```
public class LoginPortal { public WebDriver inloggen(String Omgeving, String Rol, String Browser) { 
String InlogUrl = null; WebDriver driver = anroepDriver.roepdriver(Browser); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

complete code on github: https://github.com/Yourtestprofessionals/YourCucumber

edit2: cheers for the replies so far. my problem is still not solved though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here is my modified pom.xml.  I went back to selenium-java version 2.53.1.  I also added surefire and specified Java 1.8 (Oracle).  Try this pom and let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.czeczotka.bdd</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-maven</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cucumber-jvm-maven</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <!-- ${basedir} needed in classpath so that log4j can find the log4j.properties file --> 
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Specifying the maven-compiler-plugin allows us to set default JDK -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I last point. I am using ChromeDriver 2.25.426923.

**EDIT 2**

I modified your runner. I replaced format with plugin.

```
package runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
    glue = "steps",
    features = "classpath:featurefiles/nieuwe_bevinding.feature"
)
public class RunInloggerTest {
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it didnt solve my problem though

Comment: Makes no sense.  Please post the code in LoginPortal.java, especially line 14.

Comment: public class LoginPortal {
  
  public WebDriver inloggen(String Omgeving, String Rol, String Browser) {
  
  String InlogUrl = null;
    
  WebDriver driver = AanroepDriver.roepdriver(Browser);
    
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: LoginPortal has a method inloggen which returns a webdriver element. i use it to open a chrome window. then i use another method BeoordelenLogin which runs LoginPortal and this method runs code that does the actual login and checks for a logout text somewhere. BeoordelenLogin method returns a boolean. hence the assertTrue. the driver.manage bit is line 14 by the way.

Comment: Mike, im sorry. im new to this :)

Comment: I am back and still looking.  For one thing, in your runner, only specify the directory. I.e. change features = "classpath:featurefiles/inloggen.feature" to features = "classpath:featurefiles". Wait, why aren't you using tags to control what gets executed?

Comment: In steps why are you importing org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder and cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.ToStringConverter? Try commenting them out.

Comment: Mike, i dont suppose you got a chance to look at my problem some more?

Comment: I downloaded the project and imported it into Eclipse.  I had to modify a few things in the pom.xml and delete some dependencies.  My Windows 10 guest doesn't have MySQL installed so it failed at java.lang.NullPointerException
 at codebase.mantisops_db.ReportIssue(mantisops_db.java:38)
 at steps.nieuwebevinding.i_login_with_the_parameters_and_and_and(nieuwebevinding.java:38)
 at ✽.When I login with the parameters "PRO" and "developer" and "Chrome" and "1"(featurefiles/nieuwe_bevinding.feature:8) but it got past your problem.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for all the effort so far. i tried  your proposed solutions and unfortunately the error remains. for reference, i tried inloggen.feature and removed my workaround code Checkargs. i assume you did the same for nieuwe_bevinding.feature. they both cause the same problems so it doesnt matter which one you try to run. This problem makes no sense whatsoever so i'd be ok to just leave it at that. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if this would actually solve your problem but trying won't hurt; have you tried using the regex 'wildcard': '.*'?

Like this:

```
@When("^I login with the parameters \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"")
```